# Logout is not found in partner connection

Tags: apex, integration

Doing integration with java to salesforce. For this I am using Partner connection / WSDL. But I am unable to find any logout option, for example 
`connection.logout()`

I don't know why this option is not available.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is there in partner wsdl please check the any other methods are clashing with salesforce logout or there is a potential chance currupted wsdl

Comment: It is working fine other than this issue. there are only two methods which I wrote in apex services. There is no logout() method in wsdl

Comment: Can you confirm the wsdl is apex wsdl or partner wsdl?